# como puedo enviar datos de un input tipo radio con clase hacia laravel sin tocar los names

Tags: php, javascript, html5, laravel

quisiera enviar parametros por medio de una clase en los inputs tipo radio hacia el controlador de laravel sin tocar la propiedad name

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="control-label">Sexo:</label>
    <label for="radio-1">Masculino</label>
    <input type="radio" name="masculino" id="radio-1value="1">
    <label for="radio-2">Femenino</label>
    <input type="radio" name="femenino" id="radio-2"value="1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que he realizado, tengo entendido que los input radio deben tener la misma clase, claro sí deseas solo seleccionar uno, supongamos en mi edición la clase es "sexos".

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
<label class="control-label">Sexo:</label>
<label for="radio-1">Masculino</label>
<input type="radio" name="sexos" id="masculino"value="1">//te faltaba una comilla doble al id
<label for="radio-2">Femenino</label>
<input type="radio" name="sexos" id="femenino"value="2">
```

Puedes crear una variable o las que necesites, para tomar el valor de los atributos que necesitas utilizar.

```
   $(".sexos").click(function () {
            var valorid = $(this).attr("id");
            var valor = $(this).attr("value");
    });
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: pero en laravel como hago para mandarlos, eso necesito ??